# Simulate a click on multiple Checkboxes to issue AJAX request when checkbox attribute is changed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a Matrix style Grid that allows to updatye some user permissions for items on a Per user basis.

It uses a Table grid and issues an AJAX request to update each setting instantly as clicked on.

I just added some `jQuery` code to mass check and un-check all checkboxes for a User row.

The issue I have is I need to make it also make the AJAX request for all those checkboxes in a Row when the Row is mass `checked` or `un-checked`

I have all code below for the demo and a JSFiddle demo.

**JSFiddle Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/7597y7q5/

---

**Preview Image:**
[image]

---

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Check/Un-check All checkboxes in a User Row
    $(".checkall").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // Make AJAX Request to Update User Permission setting in Backend Database
    $(".flipswitch").change(function () {
        var flip = $(this).closest('td');
        //alert("perm_id="+this.value+"&permissions=" + this.checked);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>',
            data: "perm_id="+ this.value + "&permission=" + this.checked,
            success: function() {
                flip.effect("highlight", {color:"#12D812"}, 2000)
            }
        });
    });

});
```

---

**Table HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table_header">
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th align="center">https://google.com/-1</th>
            <th align="center">https://google.com/-2</th>
            <th align="center">https://google.com/-3</th>
            <th align="center">https://google.com/-4</th>
            <th align="center">https://google.com/-5</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input class="checkall" type="checkbox"> user 1-1</td>
            <td align="center">user 1<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="0" type="checkbox" value="1">1</td>
            <td align="center">user 1<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="1" type="checkbox" value="2">1</td>
            <td align="center">user 1<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="2" type="checkbox" value="3">1</td>
            <td align="center">user 1<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="3" type="checkbox" value="4">1</td>
            <td align="center">user 1<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="4" type="checkbox" value="5">1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input class="checkall" type="checkbox"> user 2-2</td>
            <td align="center">user 2<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="5" type="checkbox" value="6">2</td>
            <td align="center">user 2<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="6" type="checkbox" value="7">2</td>
            <td align="center">user 2<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="7" type="checkbox" value="8">2</td>
            <td align="center">user 2<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="8" type="checkbox" value="9">2</td>
            <td align="center">user 2<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="9" type="checkbox" value="10">2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input class="checkall" type="checkbox"> user 3-3</td>
            <td align="center">user 3<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="10" type="checkbox" value="11">3</td>
            <td align="center">user 3<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="11" type="checkbox" value="12">3</td>
            <td align="center">user 3<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="12" type="checkbox" value="13">3</td>
            <td align="center">user 3<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="13" type="checkbox" value="14">3</td>
            <td align="center">user 3<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="14" type="checkbox" value="15">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input class="checkall" type="checkbox"> user 4-4</td>
            <td align="center">user 4<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="15" type="checkbox" value="16">4</td>
            <td align="center">user 4<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="16" type="checkbox" value="17">4</td>
            <td align="center">user 4<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="17" type="checkbox" value="18">4</td>
            <td align="center">user 4<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="18" type="checkbox" value="19">4</td>
            <td align="center">user 4<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="19" type="checkbox" value="20">4</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input class="checkall" type="checkbox"> user 5-5</td>
            <td align="center">user 5<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="20" type="checkbox" value="21">5</td>
            <td align="center">user 5<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="21" type="checkbox" value="22">5</td>
            <td align="center">user 5<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="22" type="checkbox" value="23">5</td>
            <td align="center">user 5<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="23" type="checkbox" value="24">5</td>
            <td align="center">user 5<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="24" type="checkbox" value="25">5</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input class="checkall" type="checkbox"> user 6-6</td>
            <td align="center">user 6<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="25" type="checkbox" value="26">6</td>
            <td align="center">user 6<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="26" type="checkbox" value="27">6</td>
            <td align="center">user 6<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="27" type="checkbox" value="28">6</td>
            <td align="center">user 6<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="28" type="checkbox" value="29">6</td>
            <td align="center">user 6<input checked="checked" class=
            "flipswitch" name="29" type="checkbox" value="30">6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**little CSS:**

```
table {  border: 1px solid #000;  }
th {  background-color: #CCC;  }
td {  border: 1px solid #CCC;   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will fire off a lot of requests all at once but first thing you could try is simply triggering `change` event when you set the `checked` property

```
$(".checkall").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr')
               .find(':checkbox')
               .prop('checked', this.checked)
               .change();// trigger change event
});
```

Comment: Thanks I discovered this right after posting.  I like the idea of looking/finding items only once though. +1

Comment: I'll accept your answer when the time allows me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I added a [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) call to issue/trigger a `change`...

```
$(this).parents('tr').find(':checkbox').change();
```

So updated jQuery code is...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".checkall").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        $(this).parents('tr').find(':checkbox').change();
    });


    $(".flipswitch").change(function () {
        var flip = $(this).closest('td');
        //alert("perm_id="+this.value+"&permissions=" + this.checked);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: "perm_id="+ this.value + "&permission=" + this.checked,
            success: function() {
                flip.effect("highlight", {color:"#12D812"}, 2000)
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/7597y7q5/6/ issues AJAX requests X **Number of columns** when checkbox to mass update a row is clicked now.  So ass all checkboxes in a row are checked and unchecked, there is an AJAX request for each checkbox being made as well.

Hopefully this helps others.  I posted this answer instead of deleting the question for my own personal reference in the future.

If there is a better way, i'm open to that too of course!  Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

As per @charlietfl's answer, is best to append my `change()` to the end of my current jQuery element search/lookup instead of doing a 2nd lookup to find checkboxes...

```
$(this).parents('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked).change();
```